# Convergency of series of arbitrary terms.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Recently I have been reading series Convergency, I am primarily focused on a series of alternating terms, and I read Riemann's rearrangement theorem.
With the help of the above-mentioned theorem, I showed that $1-1/2-1/3-1/4+1/5-1/6-1/ 7-1/8+1/10-.....$ this series is convergent.
My question is if take the series like

$-1 + 1/2 - 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 - 1/7- 1/8 - 1/9 + 1/10 + 1/11 + 1/12 -1/13 - 1/14- 1/15 - 1/16+1/17+1/18+1/19+1/20-1/21.....$

is this series a convergent series?

My efforts are here:

I am trying to grouping the series

$-1+(1/2-1/4+1/6-1/8+...)+(-1/3+1/5-1/7-1/9+1/11-1/13-1/15+....)=-1 +P+Q$ say, where $P=(1/2-1/4+1/6-1/8+...)$ and $Q=(-1/3+1/5-1/7-1/9+1/11-1/13-1/15+....)$,  $P$ and $Q$ both are convergent, so I think the series is convergent.

Comment: Not sure the pattern of signs is clear.

Comment: The signs pattern is following, -,+,-,-,+,+,-,-,-,+,+,+,-,-,-,-,+,+,+,+........ like that.

Comment: I suggest editing your post to include that.  Not sure your readers will take the time to sort it out for themselves.  Also, include your efforts.  How does this behave for small cutoffs?  As you are aware, it's not easy to approach the conditional convergence of general sequences.  Here, you could try to use information about the harmonic series, for instance.

Comment: Try and group the terms symmetrically , so every sequence of a few minus with the next sequence of a few pluses and see what happens